# If inside html code with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I am using asp.net webform 4.5.1 code first with entity framework. I used one repeater and bind it to my entity class. I want use if statement to decide show one DIV in this repeater or not. my code is :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ProductRepeater" runat="server"
          ItemType="Models.Product"
          SelectMethod="ProductRepeate_GetData">
          <ItemTemplate>
             <% if(Item.Rank > 5 && Item.X != null && Item.Y != null){%>
               <div>I want show this div just if my if statement is True</div>
             <%}%>
             <div >
                 <%# Item.Name%>
              </div>

           </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want show the first div just when the result of  if statement is True. the error is : The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you already got an answer, you can do it in markup also like this:

```
 <%# (Item.Rank > 5 && Item.X != null && Item.Y != null)? "<div>I want show this div just if my if statement is True</div>" : "" %>
```

Comment: I was searching Exactly for this answer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the kind of calculation that you would want to include inline; not only will it be very difficult to read, it will also be very difficult to debug.

Instead, create a label `<asp:Label ID="outputLabel" runat="server" ></asp:Label>` and set the value of the label from the `ItemDataBound` Event on the repeater.

```
protected void ProductRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;

    Label output = (Label)item.FindControl("outputLabel");
    Product product = (Product)item.DataItem;

    if (product.Rank > 5 && product.X != null && product.Y != null)
    {
        output = "I want show this div just if my if statement is True";
    }
    else
    {
        output = product.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when I use Container.DataItem instead of Item. it shows this error. The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context